# jekyll-github-metadata working locally but not in GitHub

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have my GitHub page set up as a homepage. When I develop locally I use github-metadata for displaying information about my repositories and it works fine (I even uploaded _site to show how the page is built). Nevertheless when I pushed the page to GitHub, the information is not being displayed.

Repository: https://github.com/emilioidk/emilioidk.github.io

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll-github-metadata'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

_config.yml (redundant github information for testing)

```
github_username:  emilioidk
github: emilioidk
repository: emilioidk/emilioidk.github.io
gems: ['jekyll-github-metadata']
```

Edit:
I have tried removing github from config file. No positive results.
I have tried removing Gemfile, Gemfile.lock and gems from config file. No positive result.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` as well as removing the `gems` attribute from the `_config.yml`? This is speculation, but those could be interfering with Github Page build configs

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have tried removing Gemfiles and gems from config but unfortunately the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** : I've forked your repository at https://statiktest.github.io/emilioidk.github.io/GitHub/

As you can see we have `public_repositories : false`.

I think it's a bug and you can open an issue on https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata/issues/new

**end edit /**

You problem is with you `github: emilioidk`. It becomes `site.github` and thus overrides jekyll metadatas in `site.github`.

Remove `github: emilioidk` from your **_config.yml**.

And the problem is the same locally. I'm surprised that it works for you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Actually, that config was added last just to "give it a try"...this is, to make sure the solution wasn't that silly! As you may see, I took it off now and the problem persists: locally it works but not when uploaded to GitHub

Answer (score 1):

Contacted support from GitHub, it was a problem in their end and it is solved now

> Hey Emilio,
>
> Sorry about that, we had a bug on our end that caused the github-metadata gem to stop working for about 40 hours.
>
> It should be working now though.